# EJB - Reason for home and remote interfaces

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I am new to Java EE and not getting the interfaces parts of the EJB. Could someone help to throw light on Why we need two interfaces(Home and Remote) for a session bean? Is'nt one interface suffice to call the remote ejb as in RMI?

Answer (score 3):

A home is a factory for EJB references.  In EJB 3.0+, the replacement for homes uses JNDI as the factory.  There are some advantages to using homes:

1. The overhead of JNDI Context.lookup (or even EJBContext.lookup) is likely much higher than the overhead of home.create().  If you need to create many EJB references (e.g., stateful session beans), then this overhead might be noticeable.  It is possible that the overheads of both approaches are low enough that it does not matter for your application.
2. Homes allow arguments to be passed when creating a stateful session bean.  There is no direct equivalent when using JNDI, so you must have (and remember to use) an initialize method or similar.
3. EJBHome has a getEJBMetaData that can be used to introspect an EJB.  The metadata is important for generic frameworks due to the CORBA requirement of using PortableRemoteObject.narrow (i.e., with a home lookup string, you can obtain a home, narrow to EJBHome, reflectively call create, call getEJBMeta().getRemoteInterfaceClass(), and narrow to the target type).  There is no equivalent for JNDI, but this isn't as necessary since EJB 3 remote interfaces do not need depend on RMI(-IIOP).

I sometimes wish a generic javax.ejb.EJBFactory<T> interface existed for EJB 3 interfaces to solve some of these problems.

Comment: What do you mean by `The overhead of JNDI Context.lookup (or even EJBContext.lookup) is likely much higher than the overhead of home.create()`? Don't you still have to use JNDI Context.lookup at least once either way? `Case 1`: You use Context.lookup for home and call home.create for ejbObject reference and `Case 2`: You lookup for ejbObject directly. Either way lookup has to be used. Is this correct or did I miss something? I just started learning Enterprise Java.

Comment: It's probably best to start a new question than add a comment to such an old answer.  Anyway, the point is with home.create, you can do a single lookup of the home then make several calls to create, and each call to create likely has lower overhead than each call to lookup.

Comment: Oh Got it! I was planning to ask a question but since it wasn't a big one and was dependent on this answer, thought I could try a comment first. Thanks for the reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

Back in the times of J2EE, there was the idea of having distributed enterprise beans which you'd use in your application.

While this is still possible, it's not the way you would typically use remote functionality. You either have your beans locally in the same container or you use some kind of web service (SOAP or REST).

That is one of the reasons why in Java EE 6 they introduced the No-Interface view, since this is the valid approach for most cases. You can just implement your ejb and have no interface at all.

Nevertheless, you can still have either a `@Local` or `@Remote` interface. Having a remote interface makes only sense, if you plan to expose your bean's functionality to the outside. If you always use remote views, you'd unnecessarily go through the full stack even if you call them locally.

Comment: Thanks @Geziefer, but still I am not getting why this approach(two interfaces) was used.. Isnt it possible to Expose the functionality by one interface and the client accessing that interface?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but usually your "Client" is just another part of the very same server, so it would be unnecessary to go through a remote interface.